# Modifying a primary key to make it composite

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have a table arp_table in which there are values ip,mac and time. I currently have ip as the primary key but i would like to modify so that it can become both the ip and the time. This is to enable an entry with the same ip but a different time to be entered. 
I was assuming the code

```
alter table arp_table
modify PRIMARY KEY(ip,time)
```

would work but it is not working. I am using mysql database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i hve edited the question, i am using mysql database

Comment: "*not working*" is not a valid error message in MySQL

Comment: i never said that is the error message do you see any quotes on that part]

Comment: *facepalm* He obviously meant, that you should post the actual error message. You were lucky someone answered.

Comment: @fancyPants its not about luck, its just about not asking unnecessary questions like the person who answered. If you know, spot the error and rectify. this wasn't a humongous problem

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. Are you about to argue, that it's not much easier to spot an error knowing the error message?

Comment: only when the mistake is complex, there is no need for an argument, but there is still no need for you to talk luck, that is not what this is about , let those who can rectify do so. Anyway the question was answered so let me thank you for your advice, next time i will post the error also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to drop the existing one:

```
ALTER TABLE arp_table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(ip,time)
```